# Define volatile int variable as extern int

Tags: c, gcc

What will happen if a variable is defined as `volatile int x` in `file1.c` and `extern int x` in  `file2.c` (instead of `extern volatile int x`)? Is there a chance for compiler to know that `x` is volatile and compile as such in `file2.c`.

Comment: That's what headers are for. Avoid `extern` declarations in an implementation file.

Comment: Somewhat OT, but hopefully you're not relying on `volatile` to actually do anything useful for a C variable in a multithreaded program?  See [Volatile: Almost Useless for Multi-Threaded Programming](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2007/11/30/volatile-almost-useless-for-multi-threaded-programming):  *...the use of volatile accomplishes nothing but to prevent the compiler from making useful and desirable optimizations, providing no help whatsoever in making code "thread safe".*

Comment: @AndrewHenle It is for embedded system. I don't think that it is useless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler only have knowledge of the current [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) (basically the current source file with all includes), nothing else.

If an `extern` variable is not declared using the correct type, then you will have undefined behavior.

Comment: @i486 Global variables (technically variables in *file-scope*) by default have *external linkage*. Also, a declaration without an initialization is *tentative* definition, it *might* be a definition or only a declaration. Read e.g. [this linkage reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration#Linkage) and [this external and tentative definition reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/extern) for more information.